# Is there a way to see Core Graphics drawings in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, user-interface, interface-builder, core-graphics

Making UI programmatically is very powerful.
But is there a way I would have missed to see for instance CG Graphics drawing in IB without to have to compile the code  ?

I guess no, but I'd prefer to ask to refer that after :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nop, how would IB know what to draw without compiling the code?

Comment: sure. but there are some operations that would require a lot of compile/test/refine/compile/test.
Example: you draw some frame, align etc.
btw, I will do that

Comment: @gluon I'm afraid that's your only option. Another (weird) option would be to draw all the interface on Illustrator or something like that, export to SVG and try to convert the SVG to CG calls, there's a very good blog post about converting SVG to CG but I can't remember the address...

Comment: ok fbernardo. maybe, loading a pic with a grid pre-made into an UIImage just to align, could be a way. :)

Answer (score 0):

The new answer to this question is: **Yes**.

With Xcode 6, you can make Interface Builder render your custom views. In addition, you can also make Interface Builder-inspectable properties on custom views that you can set from Interface Builder just like properties of built-in views.

All you need to do is add the line `IB_DESIGNABLE` just above the class declaration in the header. This will make Interface Builder render your custom view by invoking its `drawRect:` method.

If you also want the inspectable properties, just add `IBInspectable` to the property declarations such as: `@property IBInspectable float myValue`, and you will be able to set that property directly from Interface Builder.

With the combination of those two, I am currently designing a custom view and by changing the properties (color, stroke width etc) I can see the effects in realtime, which is probably just you were asking for.

It came a bit late, but finally, it's here.